# Транслитерация рускоязычных имен файлов

Tags: php

Пытаясь организовать мульитзагрузку файлов на сервер столкнулся с проблемой, что рускоязычные имена файлов сохраняются в виде битой кодировки (т.е. буквы заменяются иероглифами), попытался внедрить транслитерацию рускоязычных имен, но написанная мной функция не может произвести перевод, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может крыться проблема.

Код HTML страницы:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<body>
<form  name="upload"  action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="files">
<input name="file[]" type="file" value="" class="1" onChange="make_input(this);">
<input  type="submit" value="Загрузить" >
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Код скрипта JS:

```
function make_input(el) {
    if ($(el).attr("class") == 1) {
        $('<input name="file[]" type="file" value="" class="1" onchange="make_input(this);"><br>').prependTo("#files");
        $(el).attr("class", "2");
    }
};
```

Код обработчика формы upload.php:

```
<?php
include("1.php");
$uploaddir=";";
$count_file=is_array($_FILES['file']['name'])?count($_FILES['file']['name']):0;
    if($count_file>0)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$count_file;$i++)
        {
            if($_FILES['file']['error'][$i]==0)
            {
            transl($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);

                $name_file=basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
                $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$name_file;

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile))
                {
                    $file_upload['file_upload'][]=$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

                }
                else
                {
                    $file_upload['error'][]=$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                }

            }
        }
    }

echo "<ul>Файлы загружены :";
if(is_array($file_upload['file_upload']))
foreach($file_upload['file_upload'] as $var)    
{
echo "<li>{$var}</li>";    
}
echo "</ul>";

echo "<ul>Файлы не загружены :";
if(is_array($file_upload['error']))
foreach($file_upload['error'] as $var)    
{
echo "<li>{$var}</li>";    
}
echo "</ul>";
echo ($file_upload);

?>
```

И собственно код файла с функцией транслита 1.php:

```
<?php   
    function transl($text) { 
        $trans = array( 
            "а" => "a", 
            "б" => "b", 
            "в" => "v", 
            "г" => "g", 
            "д" => "d", 
            "е" => "e", 
            "ё" => "e", 
            "ж" => "zh", 
            "з" => "z", 
            "и" => "i", 
            "й" => "y", 
            "к" => "k", 
            "л" => "l", 
            "м" => "m", 
            "н" => "n", 
            "о" => "o", 
            "п" => "p", 
            "р" => "r", 
            "с" => "s", 
            "т" => "t", 
            "у" => "u", 
            "ф" => "f", 
            "х" => "kh", 
            "ц" => "ts", 
            "ч" => "ch", 
            "ш" => "sh", 
            "щ" => "shch", 
            "ы" => "y", 
            "э" => "e", 
            "ю" => "yu", 
            "я" => "ya", 
            "А" => "A", 
            "Б" => "B", 
            "В" => "V", 
            "Г" => "G", 
            "Д" => "D", 
            "Е" => "E", 
            "Ё" => "E", 
            "Ж" => "Zh", 
            "З" => "Z", 
            "И" => "I", 
            "Й" => "Y", 
            "К" => "K", 
            "Л" => "L", 
            "М" => "M", 
            "Н" => "N", 
            "О" => "O", 
            "П" => "P", 
            "Р" => "R", 
            "С" => "S", 
            "Т" => "T", 
            "У" => "U", 
            "Ф" => "F", 
            "Х" => "Kh", 
            "Ц" => "Ts", 
            "Ч" => "Ch", 
            "Ш" => "Sh", 
            "Щ" => "Shch", 
            "Ы" => "Y", 
            "Э" => "E", 
            "Ю" => "Yu", 
            "Я" => "Ya", 
            "Ъ" => "", 
            "ъ" => "", 
            "ь" => "", 
            "Ь" => "" 
        ); 
        if(preg_match("/[А-Яа-яa-zA-Z\.]/", $text)) { 
            return strtr($text, $trans);

        } 
        else { 
            return $text;                  
        }; 
    } 
?>
```

Спасибо! 
Буду очень рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1):

strtr принимает строки, а не массивы. Используйте str_replace

```
str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject);
```

Comment: В моём случае `str_replace(xxxx , $trans, $text)`, где:
`$text` - исходное имя файла; `$trans` - набор символов для замены;
а что должно быть на месте хххх?

Comment: Набор заменяемых символов. То есть, str_replace(array_keys($trans), array_values($trans), $text).  
И не забудьте записать результат в $name_file.

Comment: Сделал следующим образом:

создал массив с русскими буквами
создал массив с транслитом 

функцию оформил следующим образом:
$new_name=str_replace($rus, $eng,  $text);

где:$rus - массив с русскими буквами; $eng - массив с транслитом 

Результат: на выходе текст не прошедший замену.

Comment: Вопрос решен.
Изменением кодировки файла с функцией транслита.
Но с использованием функции предложеной Вами.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Вы применяете функцию транслитерации, но ее результат-то никуда не сохраняете.

```
transl($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
```

А нужно, например:

```
$name = transl($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
```

и далее

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.**$name**;
```

Comment: Дело в том, что в самой функции я делал промежуточные выводы, и получается всегда пустая переменная, функция просто отказывается понимать русские буквы, я уже начинаю думать, может вся проблема в кодировке...

Comment: всё равно попробывал как вы предлогаете, результат - не работает, передает исходное имя не прошедшее транслит...

Answer (score 1):

В таком варианте из массива $trans можно убрать большые буквы. Либо оставить всё как есть, но убрать из скрипта strtolower.

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9()-\.\+]/','', strtr(strtolower(trim($text)), $trans));

if($name != '') {

  return $name;

} else {

  return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего сам фаил содержащий массив хранится в одной кодировке, а загружаемый фаил в другой

копайте в сторону [мультибайтовая работа со строками](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php)
и  [iconv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

+в зависимости от настроек на сервере(php.ini) вы найдете подходящий вариант работающий у ВАС !

рабочий пример функции:

```
function transl($st,$code='utf-8'){

$st = mb_strtolower($st, $code);  
$st = str_replace(array(  
        '?','!','.',',',':',';','*','(',')','{','}','%','#','№','@','$','^','-','+','/','\\','=','|','"','\'',  
        'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','з','и','й','к',  
        'л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х',  
        'ъ','ы','э',' ','ж','ц','ч','ш','щ','ь','ю','я'  
    ), array(  
        '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',/*remove bad chars*/  
        'a','b','v','g','d','e','e','z','i','y','k',  
        'l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','f','h',  
        'j','i','e','_','zh','ts','ch','sh','shch',  
        '','yu','ya'  
    ), $st);  

return $st;  
}   


echo transl("Какаято не реальная строка @$^*^&()&(5");
```